# SQLlite: Select query with where clause is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-clause

This function always return false and cursor is always empty , even there are more the 10 records in the database i have tried querying each record against assignment id but not working.

I have copied the database from virtual device into my pc and used sqlite manger to do the same query and its working in pc and there are all records in the database.

This is my code:

```
public boolean checkAssignment(String assignmentId) {
        boolean assignmentStored = false;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS +
                " WHERE " + KEY_ASSIGNMENT_ID + " = '" + assignmentId.trim()+"'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            assignmentStored = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return assignmentStored;
}
```

Comment: The query is working. The problem is that the database is empty. Show your `SQLiteOpenHelper`-derived class.

Comment: Can you post the values of the constants you are using? Also, is the datatype of `asignmentId` text in your db?

Comment: I guess the `asignmentId` field is a numeric type. But you are treating it as if it was a string. Therefore, it won't work.

Comment: I have edited the post with images please check now.

Comment: **assignmentId** field is a numeric field but the where clause should work as it's assignmentId is exactly equal.

Comment: You have to take look of log that what sqlite server is saying

Comment: Sqlite server just returns 0 results.

Comment: `assignmentId field is a numeric field but the where clause should work as it's assignmentId is exactly equal` **NO**. Since `assignmentID` is a **number**, the `WHERE` clause will fail, if you treat it as a **string**.

Comment: I have tried with Integer also Please have a look at this screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/asoiol

Answer (score 0):

From the images that you have posted, I can see that the datatype of your `assignmentId` column is number.

So change your query like:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS +
     " WHERE " + KEY_ASSIGNMENT_ID + " = " + Integer.parseInt(assignmentId.trim());
```

Comment: I have tried with Integer value too but again the result is same.

Comment: Can you check how many rows you get without the where clause? Just to make sure, there is some data in the table.

Comment: I have got 10 rows without where clause. Please check the images in the post.

Comment: @UniqueIdentifier Which image shows that you have 10 rows in the table in the Android database? I can't find it.

Comment: Please check this image.
http://prntscr.com/arnezv
I have copied the virtual device database into pc and opened it in sqllite manager, you can see the records here.

Comment: Not on PC. Change the query in android and then see the value of `cursor.getCount()`.  There might be some issue on your db connection.

Comment: @PrerakSola Yap i am talking about android i have changed the query here in android studio and debug the app...But still the same results its just insane everything working fine just the where clause doesn't work but the same where clause work in pc with same database.

Comment: How do you get only 10 results without the "WHERE" clause if, from the print screen, I see at least 12 in that table?

Comment: I was not sure about exact count of the records so just estimated 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use it that way:

```
public boolean checkAssignment(String assignmentId) {
        boolean assignmentStored = false;    
        String[] columnsToReturn = { "KEY_ASSIGNMENT_ID"};
        String selection = "KEY_ASSIGNMENT_ID =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { Integer.ParseInt(assignmentId.trim())}; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  db.query(TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, columnsToReturn, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            assignmentStored = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return assignmentStored;
    }
```

Comment: I have created the new project and added just DataHelper class to insert and get the assignments now its working i don't know what's wrong with the other project.